# Sqlite: update DATE column, but change date only - preserve time

Tags: sqlite, date, preserve

I need to update the actual date of a ton of rows, but preserve the time already in there.  A script started incorrectly populating the rows incorrectly due to a programming error.  I could probably do this via an external script, but I figure there has to be a sqlite command to do this easily.

The column is described as this in the schema:
`logDate DATE NOT NULL,`

A sample row looks like this:
`data8|dat7|200|2011--08 00:15|12`

It SHOULD look like this:
`data8|dat7|200|2011-01-08 00:15|12`

It's done this for the past 10 days.  I can do individual updates for the past 10 days, or one big one, but I really am not sure where to start.  I haven't found much via googling.  If I do, I'll answer my own question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just did this:

```
UPDATE views SET logDate = REPLACE(logDate,'--','-01-') 
WHERE logDate LIKE '2011%';
```

Worked fine.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as answered, so that people know there is a solution when searching for similar issues. Thanks!